# Validating input field contained in table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
  <tr>
      <td>.....</td>
        <td>    
            <div class="...">
                <div class="..." id="..." style="display:block;">
                    <ul id="..." class="..." style="position:relative;">
                        <%
                            for(int i = 0;i < len;i++)
                            {
                                //get a json object
                                if(jsonobj != null)
                                {           
                                    //Get style...id..and some other values....
                        %>              
                                <li class="..." style="display:block;" id="..."> 
                                    <div style="<%=style%>">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="<%=Id%>" class="..." value="true" <%if(enabled){%> checked="checked" <%}%> onClick="..."/>
                                        <input id="inp_<%=Id%>" type="text" class="..." style="border:none;padding-left:5px;" value="<%=text%>"  title="<%=title%>">
                                    </div>
                                </li>                   
                        <%      }
                            }
                        %>
                    </ul>                                           
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

I have a table row like the above code. As you can see, there are two inputs, a checkbox and a text field. While submiting the form I want to validate the text field and show an error message with a small error icon at the right side. But since the input is in a table row I'm unable to to this.

I have a function which shows a tool tip. I just have to pass the id of the element and the message to that function. I want to validate the input field, show a small error image and call the tool tip function so that the tool tip is shown on the error image.

I want the error image to appear next to the required input field i.e., if the 3rd input field is vaidated to false, then the error should be displayed next to the 3rd

containing the input field.

How do I do it?

Comment: check out this link:  https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? DOM traversal to that element ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple task for jQuery. See the example below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btnSave").click(function(){
$(".txtvalidatorMessage").remove() // remove all messages
var inputs = $(".txtvalidator");
function ShowMessage(message, input){
var messageContainer = $("<div class='txtvalidatorMessage'>"+message+"</div>");
messageContainer.insertAfter(input)// show the message beside the input
}


inputs.each(function(){
var validationType = $(this).attr("validationType");
var require = eval($(this).attr("require"));
switch(validationType)
{
case "NotEmpty":
if ($(this).val() == "" && require == true)
ShowMessage("cant be empty",$(this))

break;

case "Number":
var isnum = /^\d+$/.test($(this).val());
if (!isnum && require == true)
ShowMessage("only number",$(this))

break;

}

});

});


});
```

```css
.txtvalidatorMessage{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table> 
<tr>
<td>
<input type='text' value="" placeholder='Cant be empty' class='txtvalidator' validationType='NotEmpty' require='true' />
</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<input type='text' value="" placeholder='only Number' class='txtvalidator' validationType='Number' require='true' />
</td>
<tr>
<td>
<input type='button' value="Validate" id='btnSave'  />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```